# Adding mask layer over fabric.js canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a problem that I'd like to add round mask on top of the editable [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/) HTML5 canvas.
Similar problem is described in this article:

[Creating an Image Mask with HTML 5 Canvas](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2011/09/creating-an-image-mask-with-html-5-canvas/)

My problem is that when I add this layer on top of the fabric.js canvas then my canvas is not editable any more inside this transparent circle. This means that the top element (the mask) captures the click/drag event, but I'd like to move the items under this mask element. Looking for ideas, how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can utilize built-in support for masks in fabric.

Here's an example of creating a circular mask at 100/100 with the radius of 200:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('...');
// ...
canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 200, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
};
```

Comment: On more issue I'd like to point out. If I try to clip transparent PNG mask (more complex shape then circle) then canvas objects are visible, but only when I use group select. Otherwise the transparent mask still "hides" object under it.

Comment: Interesting. If you file a bug on github (https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues) with simple test case, I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the support! I submitted my issue: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/90

Comment: Is possible to have the object's resize handlers outside the mask?

Comment: @kangax do we need to define ctx?? using getContext()??

Comment: @simmisimmi no, `ctx` is supplied to the function as first argument